# Private iOS Apps for small businesses

Tags: ios

I need some clarifications.

I would like to develop apps for local businesses. 
A great example is a POS system for small stores that can be run on an iPad.
I want it to be private and does not need to be on the appstore.

Is this possible for an enterprise program($299)?

If yes, can I develop another app for another purpose(on the same program), like a private appointment app?

Comment: **YES** that is fine.

Comment: Not sure what `Niche` has to do with this. Definition of Niche https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=niches&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=8WlqUoTeB4aU0QXW6oHgDA#q=niche&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about business and not code / programming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two correct approaches to accomplish your objectives.

1. Your Client can enroll in the Enterprise Development program and you would use their credentials to distribute the application.
2. You can enroll in the Standard Developer program and distribute the app to your customers via iTunes B2B Volume Purchase Program.  https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

**Note:** You should not distribute production versions of apps to clients using an ad-hoc distribution from your account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Two possible methods;

**Option1.** You can get enterprise program and you can distribute your apps to specific devices/in house easily.

**Option2.** You can just be the member of standard developer program and you can still distribute your apps up to 100 devices by using ad hoc distribution. If you choose this option, installed apps will expire in some time (like 6 months or a year) and you will need to install again.

I hope it helps...

Comment: On option 1, have unlimited installs?

Comment: Yes, there is no device limit in enterprise program...

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR  NO! Don't do it! It's a trap! If you want to be a black market developer, go through [the black market app store for jail-broken devices](http://cydia.saurik.com/)

There is only one official, legal, and endorsed by Apple way to do what you are describing and skip the "normal" App Store, and it's called the "Volume Purchase Program" and [you can read all about it here.](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/)

These other suggestions to misuse the 100 devices allowed for beta-testing should not pass your most basic sense of business skepticism or "smell test". Do you really think that Apple doesn't care at all if you completely circumvent their ecosystem to cut them out of the revenue loop as long as you "keep it under 100 sales"?

Distributing Apps under the enterprise license is for employees of YOUR COMPANY ONLY, so unless you personally own all of those stores under some giant shell company, distributing a PoS solution to every regional coffee shop is not what the enterprise program is for, (one minor extension beyond your direct employees as outlined below:)

> “Internal Use Applications developed under this Agreement may be deployed on Deployment Devices in two ways: (1) deployment for internal use by Employees, and (2) deployment for use by Customers either on Your physical premises or under the direct supervision and physical control of Your Employees in other locations, subject to Apple’s right to review and approve such deployment as set forth herein.”

As an investor, if anyone pitched me a business model of selling to local businesses as you describe by "flying under Apple's radar" with the potential to make a max of 100 sales, all while hoping the massive resources of Apple's legal department don't notice or look the other way if they do, I have to admit that I'd probably black-list them to every other Angel I know.

Comment: Apple does not include registration from other countries. How can clients avail the program?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Popeye, if you look closely at what I wrote, you'll see that I explain the Enterprise Program to him, and even quote from Apple's doc's a relevant passage about it. zeekerg's question was if he could use a program like this to distribute to many different companies (his example was a Point of Sales app for many different retail stores), which is not something the Enterprise Program supports.

Comment: @ryancumley I have just reread your answer my apologies I misread I will remove my comments. Sorry

Comment: @popeye, no apology necessary, I felt kind of bad about my tone in the original response too, I was needlessly harsh.